# Automated testing approach for Xamarin.Form Custom controls

Tags: custom-controls, xamarin.forms, automated-tests

I have a Xamarin.Form custom control for which i need to automate the testing process. To be more specific I need to test the control is rendered correctly on each platform(Android,iOS,WinPhone) with different combination of its API.
I am stuck at determining how to achieve this. 
As far as I have read through the online docs Xamarin.UITest is to test the UI of an app while my requirement is to test the control. So can this be done through Xamarin.UITest? 
My research so far has led me to believe that I should create unit tests for the control's API. The issue with this approach is that how am I suppose to access a control that has defined in a PCL in an NUnit project.

Anyone else here who has faced similar kind of situation? What is the correct approach to deal with such problems?
Any help/guidance regarding this will be highly appreciated.

TIA